# How To Assign an Existing Record to Another Record in Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an independent student table with the **last** student  with a  `Student id: 24`.

I have a post table where I assigned the `student_id` (attribute on the post table) to `24`

When I do

```
Student.last.posts
```

I am getting an empty array

```
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

I am actually expecting that particular record in the post table (which I assigned to that last student to show up)

that particular post record :

```
=> #<Post id: 9, message: "朱迪是一个不错的房东她总是让我做饭她得到了一台电视和安装电缆并没有问我们凑钱", student_id: 24, created_at: "2013-09-12 14:18:41", updated_at: "2013-09-12 14:51:26", host_id: 1> 
2.0.0-p195 :004 >
```

has a host_id: 1 because I created an entry in rails console **(to the first host)**

```
Host.first.posts.create(:message => "朱迪是一个不错的房东她总是让我做饭她得到了一台电视和安装电缆并没有问我们凑钱")
```

my host.rb model has

```
has_many :posts
belongs_to :student
```

my student.rb model has

```
has_many :hosts
has_many :posts, through: :hosts
```

my post.rb model has

```
belongs_to :student 
belongs_to :host
```

I have successfully query out that particular post (reviews of a home stay) for that particular host in my view. My next step is to show who posted that particular post for this specific host. should student_id be Student id or Student_id ? Don't know if this helps?

Comment: since a `student` has many `posts` through `host`, wouldn't you need to do something like `Student.last.hosts.last.posts` or whatever first or last on the hosts. Otherwise, change your model and remove `, through: :hosts`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your models your Host must have a student_id. It's unclear from your example, but it seems like your student_id in Host.first is not Student.last.id.

Another point which was touched on a bit by @kobaltz comment is that your Post model has the host_id and student_id. This looks like you are using it as an association. So your model should probably look like this.

post.rb

```
belongs_to :host
belongs_to :student
```

student.rb

```
has_many :posts
has_many :hosts, :through => :posts
```

host.rb

```
has_many :posts
has_many :students, :through => :posts
```